# Keep track of all minted tokens on ERC721 Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a `Smart Contract` that I'd like to build a web based marketplace app for. How can I list all available "Items" in the contract. Seeing as there is no upper limit to the number of minted Items, how can I implement pagination and search?

What is a best practice and scalable solution:

- to simply return the Items[] array
- sync the array with my database on Transfer and other events
- other suggestions?

  ```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

  contract Item is ERC721{

  struct Item{
      string name; // Name of the Item
      uint level; // Item Level
      uint rarityLevel;  // 1 = normal, 2 = rare, 3 = epic, 4 = legendary
  }

  Item[] public items; // First Item has Index 0
  address public owner;

  function Item() public {
      owner = msg.sender; // The Sender is the Owner; Ethereum Address of the Owner
  }

  function createItem(string _name, address _to) public{
      require(owner == msg.sender); // Only the Owner can create Items
      uint id = items.length; // Item ID = Length of the Array Items
      items.push(Item(_name,5,1)) // Item ("Sword",5,1)
      _mint(_to,id); // Assigns the Token to the Ethereum Address that is specified
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an `itemsCount` public property that holds the current amount of existing items, and increment it after each `items.push()`.

---

*Without pagination and search:*

Off-chain systems that want to read your data, can simply loop from `items[0]` to `items[itemsCount]` and since it's just a read operation, it doesn't require a transaction (i.e. it's free).

---

*With pagination and search:*

You can to create a `view` function that:

1. Takes `page` and `query` as arguments
2. Loops through existing `items` and if the item fits the criteria (`name` contains `query`), add it to the results array
3. Returns the results array

Note: Step 2 is actually going to be a bit more complicated in Solidity, because you can't `push` into an in-memory dynamic array. So you need to:

1. Loop through the items and find an amount that fit the criteria (up to the page limit)
2. Create a fix-length in-memory array `results`
3. Now you can loop through the items again and fill the fix-length `results` array with values

Answer (score 1):

mapping are more efficient than arrays in solidity. You could have a uint in the smart contract that keeps the count of every Item and use a getter function to get each item from whatever number you want to paginate subtracted from the item count.

```
contract Item is ERC721{

struct Item{
    string name; // Name of the Item
    uint level; // Item Level
    uint rarityLevel;  // 1 = normal, 2 = rare, 3 = epic, 4 = legendary
    uint id;
}

mapping(uint => Item) items; // First Item has Index 0
uint count;
address public owner;

function Item() public {
    owner = msg.sender; // The Sender is the Owner; Ethereum Address of the Owner
}

function createItem(string memory _name, address _to, uint level, uint rarityLevel
                    uint id) public{
    require(owner == msg.sender); // Only the Owner can create Items
        uint num = count++;
        items[num].name = _name;
        items[num].level = level;
        items[num].rarityLevel = rarityLevel;
        items[num].id = num;
        count++;
}

function getItem(uint item) public view returns(string memory _name, uint level, 
                 uint rarityLevel, uint id){
        uint level = items[item].level;
        uint rarityLevel = items[item].rarityLevel;
        uint id = items[item].id;
        string memory _name = items[item].name
        return(level, rarityLevel, id, _name)
}
```